# Using Poco DirectoryWatcher

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I want to use class Poco::DirectoryWatcher to receive notifications about new files appearing in a directory. I create DirectoryWatcher object

```
DirectoryWatcher dw (string ("dir"));
```

Then I have a problem adding a delagate to event `itemAdded`. I want to use a method onAdd of the object `listener`, that instantiates class `Controller`

```
class Controller {
  public:
  void onAdd (const void*, DirectoryWatcher::DirectoryEvent&) {
      cout << "Event" << endl;
  }
};

.....

Controller listener;
dw.itemAdde += delegate (&listener, &Controller::onAdd);
```

And here I receive compilation error. What do I do wrong and what and how must I do?

All required headers were included.

Poco library 1.45, Xubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, template expects const event arg:

```
void onAdd (const void*, const DirectoryWatcher::DirectoryEvent&) {
    cout << "Event" << endl;
}
```